# What is the damage for a 5 pound stone from telekinetic volley?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

How much damage would a 5 pound stone deal when used with [telekinetic volley](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/telekinetic-volley)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably 1d6 dmg.

From the spell: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/telekinetic-volley

> The ranged attack is made as if you had thrown the item unless it's
>   ammunition for a weapon

Throwing a stone is an improvised ranged weapon. To figure out the damage you find a similar object from the weapon table and use its damage.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons

> Sometimes objects not crafted to be weapons nonetheless see use in
>   combat. Because such objects are not designed for this use, any
>   creature that uses an improvised weapon in combat is considered to be
>   nonproficient with it and takes a –4 penalty on attack rolls made with
>   that object. **To determine the size category and appropriate damage for
>   an improvised weapon, compare its relative size and damage potential
>   to the weapon list to find a reasonable match**. An improvised weapon
>   scores a threat on a natural roll of 20 and deals double damage on a
>   critical hit. An improvised thrown weapon has a range increment of 10
>   feet.

In this case, I think the rock probably does damage similar to a club which deals 1d6 damage.